# Recursive list functions

Tags: python, list, datetime, recursion, zip

I am trying to create a recursive Python function that accepts a list of periods and consolidates them into a clean timeline. It should scan through a list and apply these rules:

- If value of **None** is found within period: **replace None with datetime.date.today()**
- If a period **starts within** and **ends within** another period: **delete it**.
- If a period **starts before** but **ends within** another period: **extend start date**.
- If a period **ends after** but **begins within** another period: **extend end date.**
- If a period **starts after** and **ends after** another period: **keep it, it's a separate period.**
- If a period **starts before** and **ends before** another period: **keep it, it's a separate period.**

It is perhaps much easier to give an example of a input and desired output *(assume values are formatted with datetime)*:

```
[I] = [(01/2011, 02/2015), (04/2012, 08/2014), (09/2014, 03/2015), (05/2015, 06/2016)]
[O] = [(01/2011, 03/2015), (05/2015, 06/2016)]  
# Notice how the output has produced a set of minimum length whilst covering all periods.

[I] = [(07/2011, 02/2015), (04/2012, 08/2014), (09/2014, 04/2015), (06/2015, None)]
[O] = [(07/2011, 04/2015), (06/2015, date.today())]
# Also, notice how the output has amended None, so it can compare dates.
```

Thanks to @khredos, I have written the following, but it still does not output the minimum string required:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Here is an example list of time periods
periods = [('01/2011', '02/2015'), ('04/2012', '08/2014'), ('09/2014', '03/2015'), ('05/2015', '06/2016')]

# this lambda function converts a string of the format you have specified to a 
# datetime object. If the string is None or empty, it uses today's date
cvt = lambda ds: datetime.strptime(ds, '%m/%Y') if ds else datetime.today()

# Now convert your original list to an iterator that contains datetime objects
periods = list(map(lambda s_e : (cvt(s_e[0]), cvt(s_e[1])), periods))

# Next get the start dates into one list and the end dates into another
starts, ends = zip(*periods)

# Finally get the timeline by sorting the two lists
timeline = sorted(starts + ends)

# Output: [datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Please also post what "errors" you are coming across

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please find errors added to the bottom of the question. I'm getting errors because I'm trying to tamper one half of a pair.

Comment: Tuples are immutable: you cannot change the value.  If you want to alter it, either make a new tuple or use a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

# Here is an example list of time periods
periods = [('01/2011', '02/2015'), ('04/2012', '08/2014'), ('09/2014', '03/2015'), ('05/2015', '06/2016')]

# this lambda function converts a string of the format you have specified to a 
# datetime object. If the string is None or empty, it uses today's date
cvt = lambda ds: datetime.strptime(ds, '%m/%Y') if ds else datetime.today()
```

The available formats are [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
# Now convert your original list to an iterator that contains datetime objects
periods = list(map(lambda s_e : (cvt(s_e[0]), cvt(s_e[1])), periods))

# Next get the start dates into one list and the end dates into another
starts, ends = zip(*periods)

# Finally get the timeline by sorting the two lists
timeline = sorted(starts + ends)
```

The output should be similar to

```
[datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Try it with any list of dates you have and you should observe the same behaviour.

HTH

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks for your quick reply and in managing to keep the code short and sweet. I'm getting errors due to the fact I cannot unpack tuples in Python 3. This line is falling over: "periods = map(lambda (s, e) : (cvt(s), cvt(e)), periods)".

Also, the output is not a list, so I don't know which dates are grouped together. Could you potentially update your answer to output a list with start and end dates as with the input list?

Comment: @AaronAvocado, just updated the answer to use python 3 syntax. Unfortunately, it looks like python 3 does not support tuple parameter unpacking which is why the error was occuring. Also the map class returns an iterator which is why the output was not a list. All fixed with this edit

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the update @khredos. The only problem is that the output array hasn't created a 'clean' timeline. The dates ('04/2015', '08/2014') shouldn't appear in the output, because they fall within the period ('01/2011', '02/2015'). The code's goal is to remove periods that start and end within another; extend periods that start within but end outside OR end within and start outside another; periods that start and end outside of another should be displayed as a separate group.